# Where is jenkins config.xml? And why is this error appearing?

Tags: jenkins, openshift, config, startup

*These two parts are together because I think they're related to each other.*

I'm running Jenkins' latest LTS war file (v1.596.2) directly from the command line. I'm using an Openshift DIY cartridge to do this.

I have set my "JENKINS_HOME" environment variable to "$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/jenkins".

```
export JENKINS_HOME=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/jenkins
```

Part 1: **where is my config.xml file**?

This works fine and most files seem to have been stored there fine, but I can't find the config.xml file... I'm probably overlooking something but I can't find it anywhere!

Part 2: **Boot up error**

I also have this error when I boot up my server using:

```
java -jar jenkins.war --httpListenAddress=$OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP --ajp13Port=-1
```

It shows this error message in the console:
http://pastebin.com/30eBBHN5

The server does boot, but it just shows this screen:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpsZ9.png

I know Openshift only allows you to bind to port 8080, otherwise you have to bind to a private port in the range 15000 - 35530 ([see this](https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202185874-I-can-t-bind-to-a-port)). However, I couldn't find any documentation on what ports Jenkins tries to bind or how to change the bindings, other than the main http (8080) and https (not used) ports.

([my jenkins cartridge URL - may not be running](https://dev-pgmann.rhcloud.com/))

**Any ideas as to what I should try?**

Comment: Hi. I'm also having trouble opening JNLP port. However, no port I've tried works (`java.net.SocketException: Permission denied`), even when trying the range 15000-35530 (the link you provided doesn't say anything on that matter - do you remember what it said?)

Comment: @Timotei, as stated in the comments of the answer below, I simply disabled JNLP by setting `<slaveAgentPort>-1</slaveAgentPort>` in the config.xml file. which I had to manually create. I don't use Jenkins slaves so I didn't want it enabled. Hope it works for you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The config.xml (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Administering+Jenkins) according to that page is stored in the JENKINS_HOME location, you need to create it there (along with any other configuration files that you need).  You should be set with having set your JENKINS_HOME to a folder in your OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR.

As for the port issue.  You might check out the current Jenkins cartridge that OpenShift provides (https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/tree/master/cartridges/openshift-origin-cartridge-jenkins) and check out some of the configuration files they are using, or their startup commands and see if that information helps you get yours running.

Also, don't use export JENKINS_HOME=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/jenkins
use this "rhc set-env " instead, it's much safer than exporting...

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tips! I haven't got the client-side rhc tool downloaded so I'll just stick with the export since this is only really for testing at the moment.

Comment: Creating the config.xml file worked! I copied across `<slaveAgentPort>-1</slaveAgentPort>` and it started!

Comment: The rhc tool is extremely useful and I highly recommend installing it.